# Add Validation in Aurelia dynamically

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to add Validation to a property on my VM "dynamically" (i.e. sometime after I register the initial rules on the VM)?

Currently, I'm registering the rules in the constructor of the VM, then a little while later, after the user has entered a bunch of data, I need to show a new field (using if.bind) and want to add validation depending on the result of a web api call..

Wondering if there's an API for this that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it without dynamically adding rule but instead you can use `satisfiesRule` and `when`, see it [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/2) in section Conditional Validation. `satisfiesRule` will only evaluated if the property that attached to it is already pass.
`when` will only evaluated the rule if the condition is true.

Additional link.
If you're using bootstrap, you can find this [useful](https://gist.github.com/jdanyow/381fdb1a4b0865a4c25026187db865ce).